# Gdb printing std::map elements

Tags: c++, gdb, stdmap

I have a std::map data member inside a class called ExecState:

```
class ExecState { // ...
std::map<int,ref<Expr> > ab_size;
// ...
};
```

When I print it from gdb I see the expected values:

```
(gdb) print state.ab_size
$1 = std::map with 1 elements = {[1] = {ptr = 0x2a221d0}}
```

However, when I try to access the element itself, gdb fails:

```
(gdb) print state.ab_size[1]
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
```

What am I doing wrong here? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I print it from gdb I see the expected values:

You see this because of the [magic of pretty-printers](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html). To see the *actual* contents of the variable, try `print/r state.ab_size`.

> However, when I try to access the element itself, gdb fails:

GDB didn't fail, but the pretty printers aren't magical enough to grant your wish. You'll have to "fish out" the value by using the *actual* data elements, not the illusion that pretty printers create (and this is hard).